# eclipse/Spring Tool Suite: alt-A stops invoking search

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Spring Tool Suite / eclipse with maven, tomcat, websphere, subversion, etc.; I've been using Search / File a lot and use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>F</kbd> to invoke it.  Suddenly it has stopped invoking that menu.  Normally when one presses <kbd>ALT</kbd>, the hot key for each menu item gets underlined in the menu item on the screen, and search has been underlining A, but now it has stopped.

I can still invoke the menu by clicking on it.  I can define <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>F</kbd> to invoke the file search, but I do wonder what happened to this menu.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: For searching a file in a project eclipse has provided Ctrl+shift+R.
Have you tried that?

Comment: alt+a/f searches files for a given string; ctrl+shift+r searches the project directories for a file which name matches a given string.  Different functions.